# c++ SDL2 fixed update movement

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to learn making a game (I'm new to c++) and I got stuck in this issue:

I have 2 threads one for rendering ( I keep no delay there so it will render frames as fast as the computer can ), and another thread for updating and handling Events like key press and such ( and I keep the delay for 8 milliseconds so it will fix update, so it won't matter on the computer fps ),
for now this thread moving the player 1 pixel to the right in every update.

The code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "GameM.h"
#include <thread>
#undef main

GameM *game = nullptr;



void rendering() {
    while (game->running()) {
        game->render();
    }
}
void updating() {
    while (game->running()) {
        game->handleEvents();
        game->update();
        SDL_Delay(8);
    }
}

int main()
{
    game = new GameM();
    game->init("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640,400,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN|SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS);

    //thread initialize
    std::thread rendering(rendering);
    std::thread updating(updating);

    //Makes main thread to wait to the threads to finish
    rendering.join();
    updating.join();

    //cleans
    game->clean();
    return 0;
}
```

Though when I run the program:

1. sometimes the player just gets stuck for a second and then keeps moving normally.
2. when I run the program, the mouse goes to wait icon and sometimes the program just crashes saying the program isn't responding.

Need your help smart people :)

EDIT3:

```
GameM *game = nullptr;
const float FPS = 60.0;
const float desFPS = 1000.0 / 60.0;
Uint32 firstframe;
float delta;

void updating() {
    while (game->running()) {
        firstframe = SDL_GetTicks();
        game->handleEvents();
        game->update();
        delta = SDL_GetTicks() - firstframe;
        if (desFPS > delta) {
            SDL_Delay(desFPS - delta);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    game = new GameM();
    game->init("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640,400,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN|SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS);

    std::thread updating(updating);

    while (game->running()) {
        game->render();
    }

    updating.join();

    game->clean();
    return 0;
}
void GameM::handleEvents() {
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            isRunning = false;
            std::cout << "STOP" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void GameM::update(){
    dstR.x += 1;

}
void GameM::render() {
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, tex, NULL, &dstR); // render asset to window
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

Comment: I can't say much since I haven't seen the full code, but have you made sure the threads are synchronized and not trying to access the same resource at the same time?

Comment: @HristijanGjorshevski Hello, the update is taking a texture and moving it's x value and render is rendering it. I will edit the post so you can see. I think you're right they touch the same resource but how do I avoid it then ? check if it is in use in another thread ?

Comment: Since you're new, I'd say you avoid it by using a single thread.

Comment: Also, `SDL_Delay(8);` could be problematic. Rather than using a fixed delay, you should measure time needed to run update functions, and subtract it from the desired update period (`8` in this case).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Even when I try to do this with only 1 thread. the player still gets stuck for 1 second each few seconds. I will edit so you will see the code. and it uses what you said in your comment.

Comment: It probably shouldn't cause the problem you're asking about.

Comment: I suggest printing current time after each function in your loops to figure out where it gets stuck.

Comment: You don't seem to have event loop or even check return status of `PollEvent`, so if you get more than one event per iteration your events will be lagging behind, and if there is no event - you're processing garbage data, which may be `SDL_QUIT`. There is no synchronisation on your rectangle, so you may access stale data. But most of all - SDL doesn't really allow (stated in doc) separating rendering from the thread that created window/renderer (some implementations may work sometimes, others like opengl will collapse instantly), and in some cases separating event handling is dangerous too.

Comment: @keltar So I made just one thread for the updating and the main loop keeps the render function. But still, same issue, the window gets a freeze for a second after every few seconds. I will update the code above so you can see the updated code I tried after your comment. (EDIT 3) + I updated the code with the handleEvent function so you can see that I do poll events while there is no left

Comment: @DanielNagornov https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent says "As this function implicitly calls SDL_PumpEvents(), you can only call this function in the thread that set the video mode. ", which is a little outdated (there is no video mode set in SDL2), but still reflects state of things. Renderer documentation says more or less the same thing. Most of the times this kind of limitations is not of SDL origin itself, but underlying operating/windowing system.

Comment: @keltar I'm super confused ... I'm not using threads at all now, I just use the main thread with a while that goes to handling events , update and render , as you said they need to be in the same thread that made them. And the program just doesn't want to work still and keeps crashing and now nothing works. 
I'm losing my sanity :(

Comment: @DanielNagornov the code in question have at least 2 threads. Consider making minimal example that can be copied to single file and compiled separately. It is quite possible you'll find where problem lies while doing so, but even if not - at least it could be checked by others. It is quite problemmatic to talk about a code I can't fully see.

Comment: Why the `#undef main`?